# Convert Git tag to Python version on the command line in Gitlab CI

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, setuptools-scm

In a Gitlab CI pipeline, I want to check that the package that was just uploaded to a registry is there and works well. What I do is basically:

```yaml
[…]

stages:
  - […]
  - deploy
  - deploytest

pip-upload:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /v[1-9].+/'
  script:
    - python3 setup.py sdist
    - python3 -m twine upload --repository-url […] dist/*

test-pip:
  stage: deploytest
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /v[1-9].+/'
  script:
    - python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url […] --upgrade --pre "mypackage==$PACKAGE_VERSION"
    - cd /tmp
    - python3 -m pytest --pyargs mypackage
```

This however requires the creation of the Python version from the git tag on the command line. I use **setuptools_scm** in my package. I there a way to call this package in a way that it returns the version corresponding to a particular git tag?

Comment: It seems like what you have works? Or do you want to test your package before uploading it to the package registry?

Comment: I want a final test that the package that I uploaded to the registry is working correctly, by downloading/installing that specific version from the registry and running its tests. For this, I need to extract the version number and give it as an argument to the pip installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `python -m setuptools_scm` to get the version. See `python -m setuptools_scm --help` for additional options.

You can also run `python setup.py --version` to get the version (assuming `setuptools-scm` is installed).